# Disabling editor in Joomla modules section

Tags: joomla, editor

I want to disable the HTML editor(Tiny MCE/Xstandard lite 2.0) and enable Editor - No editor option in module section of Joomla. Please Advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its part of the user settings. Go to the administration interface.

- Site -> User Manager
- Select what user you want to set the editor for.
- Within "Parameters / Basic Settings" select box "User Editor", select "Editor - No Editor"

Comment: I know this one but I want to disable for a specific module say mod_html...how can I do that...?